# HLSL Texture Array: Texture2D vs TextureCube

Tags: arrays, binding, directx, hlsl, texture-mapping

I'm attempting to implement a dynamic/bindless texture system in HLSL using an array of texture objects to contain all registered textures. Basically each time a texture is rendered, it automatically kicks the oldest one out and binds to its array slot.

However, it seems that defining this texture array as type `Texture2D` prevents the binding of `TextureCube` resources, such as for specular IBL or irradiance maps.

Is there any way around this? Is it possible to define an array of some type that would allow both of these types of textures to be binded to the same array? Or will it be required to define a separate array for each type of texture?

It seems like having a single array would increase the efficiency of the "kick the oldest one out" logic. If 2+ arrays are used, then we could have situations where textures are just hanging around because their type of texture isn't being registered, while another type of texture is starving for open slots. Or maybe I'm just over thinking it.

If anyone has any suggestions or advice on how to make it work, I appreciate the input. I am using DirectX 12 + Diligent Engine for the API.

Answer (score 0):

After more work and experience, I can confirm that it is indeed necessary to have two texture arrays, as far as I can tell. If anyone knows of a way to change that fact, please post another answer, and I will accept it as the answer.

Basically, I just defined the standard texture array to be large, while defining the cube map array to be small, to balance out the sharing. It's not ideal as far as sharing goes, but in my case (probably most cases), cube maps will not be used as often as standard textures.